# Securely Show and post a Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

suppose you show a form using beginform

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsLock, new { @Class = "col-md-12 control-label" })
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeLockUser", "UserAdmin", new { area = "Admin", id = Model.UserId }, FormMethod.Post))
                                    {

                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Url.Action("Details", "UserAdmin", new { Area = "Admin", id = Model.UserId }))
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            @Html.TextBox("LockStatus", Model.IsLock ? "غیر فعال" : "فعال", new { @class = "col-md-12 form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">@(Model.IsLock ? "فعال شود" : "غیرفعال شود")</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

before submitting I can easily change the Id in the post address so the form will manipulate another record!!!

is there any method to solve this security problem?

thank you

Comment: You can try to add a validation on server side. To check the user ID, because not sure what you how your admin and restriction work.

Comment: when user submit form I dont know about the Id of the first record

Comment: then do a validation on that user id, after the user submitted the form, do a query from the user, and check which id he/she can edit, if the requested id is in the list - means it is correct behavior , if the requested id is not in the editable list, throw modelstate error.

Comment: Use a Guide for your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UserId in front-end, you can get the current logged in user in the Controller inside ActionResult like

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;


string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Get the UserId after submitting then use it.

Comment: it was an example I mean any other identification of an record

Comment: My suggestion is you use a framework like aspnetboilerplate.